# Convert a CoffeeScript project to JavaScript (without minification)?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, coffeescript, npm

We're using a particular jQuery *plugin* written in CoffeeScript at work and I'm hoping I can convert the project into somewhat normal looking JavaScript.  The library looks like it's structured really well (good OOP practices), but I'd really like it if I could explore it's source code without having to learn all the tricks that CoffeeScript entails.

Comment: Coffee script outputs valid javascript, but it's not meant to be human friendly.

Comment: There's a difference between 'documented' and 'well documented'.  The latter is fairly rare, but you can tell because all your questions are answered.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Compiling CoffeeScript into JavaScript usually results in JS that is fairly readable. You can convert snippets on the fly on the "Try CoffeeScript" tab of [the CoffeeScript homepage](http://coffeescript.org), or via [the CoffeeScript command line tool](http://coffeescript.org/#usage).

There are also tools like [decaffeinate](https://github.com/decaffeinate/decaffeinate) that convert CoffeeScript source to modern JavaScript.

If you know JavaScript and just want to be able to read the source of a file, a perusal of the CoffeeScript homepage will probably give you enough understanding of CoffeeScript to read CoffeeScript sources fairly easily.

Comment: Yeah, coffeescript is not that tricky

Comment: 2nd link is broken.

Comment: This also works: https://awsm-tools.com/code/coffee2js

Answer (score 18):

There's also this online compiler http://js2coffee.org/ that can convert coffeescript to and from javascript

Comment: I installed their cli version, but maybe I'm too stupid to make it convert a simple coffee script into js.

Comment: It only converts js TO coffeescript, not vise versa as asked in the question.

Comment: It works in both ways. I just paste the coffeescript code and it shows me js as a preview.

Answer (score 7):

On http://coffeescript.org/ there is a tab - try CoffeeScript

Stick the coffee in the left side and JS pops up on the left

Answer (score 5):

[BinaryMuse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62082/binarymuse) pointed you [to the CoffeeScript command line tool](http://coffeescript.org/#usage), but I'd thought I post the actual command for posterity:

- Compile a directory tree of .coffee files in src into a parallel tree
  of .js files in lib:

  coffee --compile --output lib/ src/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to convert confeescript into JavaScript using their compiler, once you have that - you can go ahead and structure the JavaScript according to your style guide.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try Depercolator which wraps up a bunch of commands together (includes decafinate, cjsx-transform, react-codemod,
prettier).

The writeup: https://blog.bugsnag.com/converting-a-large-react-codebase-from-coffeescript-to-es6/ and GH repo: https://github.com/bugsnag/depercolator